Office Script Excel Pivot Table Sum is not working for the format h:mm
I'm using Office Script to generate a pivot table and for summarize using following script where Due is in the format of h:mm
pivotTable.addDataHierarchy(pivotTable.getHierarchy("Due")).setSummarizeBy(ExcelScript.AggregationFunction.sum)
It is throwing error as missing argument or invalid argument
I want to summarize the Due column in pivot table which is in the format of h:mm
The expected output is working in local excel, not working at online workbook
